# get n-3 or n-x months (~90 days before) from a date in Decimal (8, 0) format with year change impact in SQL Server and DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, db2-400

I have a Decimal column (Decimal (8, 0)) that represents date in YYYYMMDD format. For example, 20200101.
Now, I want to get 20191001. How can I do this?

Comment: SQL Server? Or DB2?

Comment: Need both please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: In this examples your column with int data type is called `date_col` and table is called `test`.

Try this on **SQLSERVER**:

```
select dateadd(DAY, -90, convert(date, convert(char(8), date_col, 23))) 
from test;
```

`DATEADD` will substract 90 days from the date.

[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59eb64cfddc17efb1839cc002f65d582)

Here is how you can get the exact result **20191001**

```
select convert(char(8), dateadd(DAY, -92, convert(char(8), date_col)), 112) 
from test;
```

[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1578aa926e168fc7af9393bdfe6abbf6)

Try this on **DB2**:

```
select date(to_date(date_col, 'yyyymmdd')) - 90 days 
from test;
```

[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=57f2df83163ba0cd54106ea118e51a8b)

I see that you want the exact **20191001** result. Here is the example for DB2:

```
select to_char(to_date(date_col, 'yyyymmdd') - 92 days, 'yyyymmdd') 
from test;
```

[Here is the DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a7cb2ed209072d09edbf5f465c534ba4)

Comment: What is 'to_date'?

Comment: It converts value to date type: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=57f2df83163ba0cd54106ea118e51a8b

Comment: Sql DBx returns 

SQL0171 - Argument 1 of function TO_DATE not valid.

Comment: And what do you put in it ? Your column with int type?

Comment: Its Decimal (8, 0).

Comment: Try this: `select to_char(to_date(cast(date_col as varchar), 'yyyymmdd') -92 days, 'yyyymmdd') from test`  And what is this: "Should I expect an answer? " ? Was the answer helpful in any way so far? If yes, up vote ...

Comment: Returns: SQL0604 - Attributes not valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206846/discussion-between-vboka-and-fasih-ullah-khan).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143431/put-date-conversion-in-where-clause-db2-sql

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(dd, -92, convert(date, convert(varchar, '20200101'))), 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

**DB2:**

```
VALUES DATE(TO_DATE(rtrim(char(20200101)), 'yyyymmdd')) - 3 month;
```

[dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=32b7cf8266dd9b59d58ab34b1e659d0f)

Comment: Returns: SQL0171 - Argument 1 of function TO_DATE not valid.

Comment: @fasihullahkhan What's your db2 version and platform? Try the updated example with explicit `int` to `varchar` data type casting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143431/put-date-conversion-in-where-clause-db2-sql

Comment: @fasihullahkhan Why do you provide here a link to another question? Does the solution provided resolve the problem you specified here?

Comment: Yes, I have my solution. I want you to take a look at another of my problem if you have time.