# Put date conversion in where clause db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have the following query. And I am calculating on `MYDATE` column which is a `DECIMAL(8, 0)` data type which stores datea in numeric form in YYYYMMDD format like this 20191107.

```
SELECT DECIMAL((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST(CAST(MYDATE AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)), 'yyyymmdd') - 3 MONTHS, 'yyyymmdd')), 8, 0) FROM PDF_TABLE;
```

It works fine. However, when I use the above conversion in a `WHERE` clause like below, query does not return anything.

```
SELECT * FROM PDF_TABLE WHERE MYDATE = DECIMAL((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST(CAST(MYDATE AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)), 'yyyymmdd') - 3 MONTHS, 'yyyymmdd')), 8, 0);
```

**Example**

[image]

Above is the data as is. Now I pass the date 20200601 as parameter in the `WHERE` clause of the following query, it should return the following row after subtracting 3 months from 20200601.

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM PDF_TABLE WHERE MYDATE = DECIMAL((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST(CAST(MYDATE AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)), 'yyyymmdd') - 3 MONTHS, 'yyyymmdd')), 8, 0);
```

Comment: Sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: It is just a decimal data type returning date in numeric form in YYYYMMDD format like this 20191107.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as is:

```
WITH MYTAB (PDF_VOLUME, MYDATE) AS
(
VALUES
  ('110 GB', DEC(20200101, 8))
, ('120 GB', DEC(20200301, 8))
, ('390 GB', DEC(20200601, 8))
)
SELECT * 
FROM MYTAB
WHERE MYDATE = DEC(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CHAR(CAST(? AS DEC(8))), 'YYYYMMDD') - 3 MONTH, 'YYYYMMDD'), 8);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to get exactly from your question. Provide some artificial example of table data and the result you want to get. For example, consider a table with 3 rows and with the following dates there: 20200101, 20200301, 20200601. What do you want to get?

Comment: Use a parameter marker like in the updated example corresponding to your programming environment then.

Comment: No, it has to iterate through the table and -3 every date.

Comment: The solution provided corresponds the problem stated as is. You get 1 row based on a parameter provided. You have changed the problem description a number of times already. Please, either correct your sample data and the result desired or ask another question with such an information.

Answer (score 0):

How could it possibly return anything?

`WHERE MYDATE = DECIMAL((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CAST(CAST(MYDATE AS INT) AS VARCHAR(8)), 'yyyymmdd') - 3 MONTHS`

Dropping the conversions, you're asking `WHERE MYDATE = MYDATE - 3 months`

That's never going to be equal... Perhaps you forgot to change the inner `MYDATE` to `CURRENT_DATE` or something?  That would also require the conversion to change..

Personally, I use a user defined function for this type of conversion; either write it yourself or download Alan Campin's free [iDate](http://think400.dk/downloads.htm) source

`WHERE MYDATE = ConvertToIDate(CCURRENT_DATE - 3 months, '*CCYMD');`